# Cannot read property 'PreviewThemeSideBar' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am using React map and I am getting the following error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'PreviewThemeSideBar' of undefined**

I don't understand in any way why I get undefined because I checked the imported component where I pass props and there I get all the data, see

[image]

[image]

**SeleceColorsTheme.js**

```
export default function SelectColorsTheme(props) {
    const groupSize = 3;

    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(false);

    const setBorder = (index) => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    };

    const rows = SideBarColors.map(function (col, index) {

        const selectBorder = classNames({
            'builtin_theme_preview': true,
            'selectBorder': index === selectedIndex ? 'selectBorder' : null
        });
        // map content to html elements
        return <SelectThemeContent {...props} selectBorder={selectBorder}
                                   col={col} setBorder={setBorder} index={index}/>
    }).reduce(function (r, element, index) {
        // create element groups with size 3, result looks like:
        // [[elem1, elem2, elem3], [elem4, elem5, elem6], ...]
        index % groupSize === 0 && r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(element);
        return r;
    }, []).map(function (rowContent) {
        // surround every group with 'row'
        return <div className="SelectThemePictures_Separator">{rowContent}</div>;
    });
    return <div className="container">{rows}</div>;
};
```

**SelectThemeContent.js**

```
export default function SelectThemeContent(props) {
    const selectBorder = props.selectBorder;
    const col = props.col;
    const setBorder = props.setBorder;
    const index = props.index;
    return(
        <div className={selectBorder} key={index} onClick={() => props.SideBarPageContent(col) || setBorder(index)}>
            <div style={{ background: col.PreviewThemeSideBar }} className="builtin_theme_preview__nav">
                <div className="builtin_theme_preview__search" />
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added a check condition to each props, example

```
<div style={{ background: col && col.PreviewThemeSideBar }}</div>
```